# how to iterate over an array correctly in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used forof but the React swears that it is not an array (not iterable).
what is the right thing to do?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./productLists.css";

import products from "../../data/products.json";

import { useSlider } from "../../hooks/useSlider";
import Card from "../Card/Card";

const ProductLists = ({ head, title, category }) => {
    const sliderLineRef = useRef();
    const [init] = useSlider(sliderLineRef, 400);

    useEffect(() => {
        init();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="productList container">
            <h3 className="head">{head}</h3>
            <h2 className="title">{title}</h2>

            <div ref={sliderLineRef} className="productList__list row">
                {products.map((p, i) => {
                    for (const c in category) {
                        if (p.category == category[c]) {
                            return <Card key={i} product={p} />;
                        }
                    }
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductLists;
```

```
{products.map((p, i) => {
                    for (const c of category) {
                        if (p.category == c) {
                            return <Card key={i} product={p} />;
                        }
                    }
})}
```

I thought that at the first match it would return the card element

Comment: Please add the `products.json` file

Comment: Is `category` an array? Is `products`?

Comment: you probably want to iterate over the json object using `Object.entries(your_obj)` and then use `.map` over that array ...

Comment: Can you add the `products.json` content ? It's hard to see if you're doing it correctly.
But as it's a`json` file. All I can say is that `products.map` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./productLists.css";

import products from "../../data/products.json";

import { useSlider } from "../../hooks/useSlider";
import Card from "../Card/Card";

const ProductLists = ({ head, title, category }) => {
  const sliderLineRef = useRef();
  const [init] = useSlider(sliderLineRef, 400);

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  // Filter products by category here. Manipulation should be handled pre-rendering.
  const filteredProducts = products.filter((p) => category.includes(p.category));

  return (
    <div className="productList container">
      <h3 className="head">{head}</h3>
      <h2 className="title">{title}</h2>

      <div ref={sliderLineRef} className="productList__list row">
        {filteredProducts.map((product, index) => (
          <Card key={index} product={product} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductLists;
```

Comment: it will be great if you provide good naming convention like below:
```
{filteredProducts.map((product, index) => (
          <Card key={index} product={product} />
        )}
```

Comment: Thanks at the entrance I had an array, the error was that I was iterating through the array inside the map